# in Vim, how can i select enclosing block or paragraph

Tags: vim, gvim, vim-plugins

I want to select a current block recursively .

for example i have this ruby code

```
1 def function
2   if true
3     if also_true
4       do this
5     end
6   end
7 end
```

for example im in the 4th line now. and when i press something, the visual block select the line 3-5
and if i press it again, it will select 2-6, and if i press it again it will select 1-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible natively in C, C++ and other languages using brackets to delimit "blocks" (with `va{`) but not in Ruby.

You'll need [a plugin](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2010/12/a-text-object-for-ruby-blocks/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is [matchit plugin](https://github.com/tsaleh/vim-matchit) for this kind of job.